# WPF. ListBox выбор элемента с помощью колеса мыши

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день.

Возникла необходимость что бы при прокрутке ListBox не просто скролился, а что бы с помощью колеса можно было выбирать следующий элемент в ListBox.

**Пример:** ListBox содержит 100 элементов. Выбран, предположим, 10. Начинаем прокручивать колесо мыши, 10 элемент теряет фокус, 11 становиться выбранным и т. д.

Как получить подобный эффект?

Comment: Странно. Вы специализируетесь на C# и WPF что бы утверждать что это формальный вопрос?

Comment: @Timich, Следующий элемент должен выделяться, когда текущий выходит из области видимости или просто при прокрутке колеса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code-behind:

```
private void ListBox_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    bool isScrollUp = e.Delta > 0;  
    bool isIndexOutOfRange = (ListBox.SelectedIndex < 1 && isScrollUp) || (ListBox.SelectedIndex > ListBox.Items.Count && !isScrollUp);
    if (isIndexOutOfRange) return;

    int scrollStep = 1;
    if (isScrollUp) scrollStep = -1;
    ListBox.SelectedIndex += scrollStep;
    ListBox.ScrollIntoView(ListBox.SelectedItem);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" 
         PreviewMouseWheel="ListBox_OnPreviewMouseWheel" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно.

Comment: @Timich, Пожалуйста! Рад, что помог.